# How can I verify that Update 1 for TFS 2012 is installed or not?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have TFS 2012 installed on a server and I want to verify that Update 1 has been installed or not. I am trying to install the TFS Power Tools for Update 1 but ran into an issue running the backup wizard in the admin console. I am suspicious that the problem is because I do not have Update 1 installed on TFS but want to make sure before I go through the lengthy process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To verify that your TFS 2012 has been updated, start your TFS Administrator Console. Then select Application Tier and then Installed Updates.

Here's an example:

[image: TFS 2012 Administrator Console]

Comment: Thank you aclear16 and Morton for your answers. Both were very helpful and if I could I would select both as the answer. Since I had to select one I went with Morton's because it will also work with future updates.

Answer (score 1):

If your web access menu bar is blue, you have update 1. If it is black, you do not.

Below are links to webpages with screenshots of the two different UI's.

Old UI (no update 1)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/govdev/archive/2012/09/06/license-the-new-tfs-2012-agile-planning-boards.aspx

New UI (with update 1)
http://almsweden.com/magnust/2012/11/27/visual-studio-2012-update-1/

Comment: Are you referring to the bar at the very top of the web page that says "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012" in the left corner and the right corner has a a "Projects" menu and the user display name?

Comment: Yes. It also contains the settings wheel option thing.